# Outlook Addin Office Intitalize function in visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, outlook-web-addins

I am developing an outlook addin using visual studio 2017 outlook web addin template.

I want to handle the event when the addin was first installed.

How can I get the installation event.I refered [this](https://apac01.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.office.com%2Freference%2Fadd-ins%2Fshared%2Foffice.initialize&data=02%7C01%7C%7C6f23ad13aa0b42d4790708d5fc352954%7C518f9b7af73549919c1748802cd8480a%7C0%7C0%7C636692227603824340&sdata=GKhXbUf8j61qSiT1OpAGZd2R9OWlZIH1BBW0NwggU0Q%3D&reserved=0) link but its not giving me any event information for addin.

Comment: Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44459540/determining-first-run-of-office-add-in)

Comment: Are you looking for an installation event or a launch event? Office.initialize will tell you when your add-in is launched. We don't have support for an installation event today.

Answer (score 0):

[Office.initialize](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/shared/office.initialize.md) is used for determining when an add-in is launched and the runtime is ready. When the event is invoked, it means that all Office.js APIs are ready to use. There is no event for when add-ins are installed. If you are looking to create a "First-Run" Experience, you may use the RoamingSettings object to set some kind of mark if user went through your guide and doesn't want to see it any longer. This object will be available right after Office.initialize, so you can try to get this mark (key) and redirect to your app page(s) or your guide page(s) according.